# SoundPlayer on Visual Studio 2017 Mac outputs no sound

Tags: c#, audio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-mac, soundplayer

I have instantiated a `System.Media.SoundPlayer` and I am (trying to) use it to play a .wav file. However, as you may have picked up from the title of this, it isn't working (no sound is being outputted). I am using C# and creating a Console application in Visual Studio 2017 **Mac**. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO; // Not needed yet
using System.Media;

namespace mathsTestConsoleC
{
    public class OutputClass
    {    
        public void PlayMusic()
        {
        SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer
        {
            SoundLocation = @"/Users/felix/Projects/mathsTestConsoleC/mathsTestConsoleC/backgroundMusic.wav"
        };

        player.Load();
        player.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

(I realise that you don't necessarily need to use `player.Load();` because the `player.Play();` includes that.)

This doesn't work either:

```
        public void PlayMusic()
        {
            SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer
            {
                SoundLocation = "/Users/felix/Projects/mathsTestConsoleC/mathsTestConsoleC/backgroundMusic.wav"
            };

            player.Load();

            Thread.Sleep(500);

            if (player.IsLoadCompleted == true)
            {
                player.Play();
            }

            else if (player.IsLoadCompleted == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("player.IsLoadCompleted == false");
            }

            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("player.IsLoadCompleted == not set");
            }

        }
```

When I call `PlayMusic()`, my application doesn't play the .wav file that I have given it.

I hope you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mono` substitutes the Windows-specific with calls to the ALSA (Advanced Linux Sound Architecture) specific `libasound.so` library.

Re: http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page

The easy way to play audio from a console app on the Mac is to shell a process and run `afplay`:

```
afplay

    Audio File Play
    Version: 2.0
    Copyright 2003-2013, Apple Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Specify -h (-help) for command options

Usage:
afplay [option...] audio_file
```

Otherwise you can create a `Xamarin.Mac`-based app and you would have full access to the audio system so you could use `NSSound` or the `CoreAudio` framework.